# Search bar прячет под собой section title при скролле

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

Search bar добавлен в tableView в tableHeaderView. Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы название секции при скролле "прилипала" не к статус бару а к Search bar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
//------Настройка Search Controller--------\\
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    // 2
    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    // 3
    resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    // 4
    resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    // 5
    resultSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
    // 6
    resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    // 7
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена с помощью сдвига отображаемого контента.

В функции viewDidLayoutSubviews() задаем сдвиг контента self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(42, 0, 0, 0), если needContentOfset == true, где 42-насколько нужно сдвинуть вниз.

Для того, чтобы сверху таблицы не отрисовывалось пустое пространство, убираем сдвиг, как только оказываемся вверху таблицы:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 44
    {
        needContentOfset = false
        viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }
}
```